App service authentication to Application Insights through RBAC in Terraform
I am trying to eliminate using connection strings in my azure infra that is created using terraform. I am planning to assign specific rbac roles to resources like web app, function app etc to make them connect to Keyvault, storage account, cosmos db etc. How to do the same for Application insights? if i grant Application Insights Component Contributor to the managed identity of the app service, how do i point it to which application insights it should connect to? is using APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY or connection string mandatory here? or can i pass this somewhere azurerm_application_insights.example.app_id ?
Thanks in advance.

Connection String still needs to be used - but with Entra auth (by using Managed Identities) the connection string becomes just resource identifier + ingestion endpoint and should not be considered secret. To ensure that nobody can ingest with a connection string (instrumentation key) alone you will need to Disable Local Auth in Application Insights resource.

The right way of securely ingesting data into Application Insights consists of a few steps:

Disable local authentication for Application Insights resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-ad-authentication?tabs=net#disable-local-authentication)
Use Connection String, it contains ingestion endpoint and instrumentation key. With local auth disabled, the instrumentation key becomes just a resource identifier and not a secret. Knowing it alone is not enough to ingest data.
Configure and enable Microsoft Entra ID-based authentication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-ad-authentication?tabs=net#disable-local-authentication). This includes a few sub-steps:

Create an identity (for instance, System Managed Identity)
Give it Monitoring Metrics Publisher role to target Application Insights resource
Ensure that your app uses this identity (above link has examples for various languages)




You can get the System Managed Identity a few different ways. For your use case, when the Web App is deployed, the principal ID will be returned as output.
If this isn't suitable, you can get it with PowerShell or Azure CLI.
CLI:
az webapp identity show \
    --resource-group MyResourceGroup \
    --name MyAppService \
    --query principalId \
    --output tsv

However. To send logs and telemetry data to App Insights, the instrumentation key must be provided in the connection string. The best workaround for this would be to use Azure KeyVault.
Bearing in mind that this adds a bit of complexity and more security considerations to the solution, and the fact that the instrumentation key isn't as sensitive as - for example - a database connection string, you may want to reevaluate whether this is really necessary. If you do want to go down this route, read on.

Create your KeyVault
Add a secret to KeyVault with the instrumentation key value
Create an access policy
Grant the system managed principal of your app the GET permission on secrets
In the app config's App Insights connection string, reference the KeyvaultSecret like this:

...InstrumentationKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://MyKeyVault.vault.azure.net/secrets/InstrumentationKey/...
When the App Service runtime sees this in the config, it automatically fetches the secret from KeyVault using the identity of the app.

While instrumentation key can be used as a secret, the correct way is to disable local auth for Application Insights. With this the instrumentation key becomes a resource identifier and cannot be used to ingest data (without Entra auth). Not disabling local auth/fetching it from KeyVault is not recommended practice.

@ZakiMa The OP just wants to get rid of connection strings in Terraform for their Azure infrastructure. There are other considerations disabling local auth, like not being able to use API keys any more, machines/apps that don't run in the context of an Azure AD principal, etc. It may not be specifically recommended for App Insights, but using KeyVault secrets for storing configuration values is completely valid because of the ease of dynamically loading it on application startup in Azure, and limiting access to those values. Hasnt been documented is not the same as bad practice.

the OP mentioned managed identity of app service. When ingestion is done using Microsoft Entra Auth then local auth should be disabled. When it is disabled - then Instrumentation Key becomes a resource identifier. Entra Auth + Local Auth makes sense only during transition period (from Local Auth to Entra Auth).
Your approach does provide a better way to secure Instrumentation Key. And this definitely should have been considered before introduction of Entra auth. But now this doesn't bring extra value while introducing more complexity and keeping the setup less secure.
